# document.elementById returns null after jQuery loads external content with .load() or .post()

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to load some data inside a div, after posting some options. The returned data also contains a dynamically generated form. After the data has loaded, I need to get the form values using getElementById(name), but it does not work (returns null).

I have tried sending and loading the results with .load() and .post()

Example code:

```
//function to load data
function loadProductPrices(var1)
{
    //#thisProductPrices is the data container
    $('#thisProductPrices').load('filename.php', { 'var1': var1});
}

//function to get element value after previous function has been called 
//(this one is called by a button that is part of the content that has 
//been generated by the previous call) 
function getAndSaveValue(elementID)
{
    var thisValue = document.getElementById(elementID).value; // this returns null (?)
    // after I have the new value I will post and save, using jquery again.
}
```

The html generated by loadProductPrices() returns a list of items

```
PriceValue
<input type="text" id="price_productID" value="PriceValue" />
<input type="button" value="save new price" onclick="getAndSaveValue(price_productID)" />
// the above button calls getAndSaveValue, in order to retrieve the new price 
//and save it...
//however it returns null.
```

Any suggestions? thnx!

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery inside `getAndSaveValue` ?

Comment: @Felix Kling: Probably won't work either, and it's slower for such a simple thing :P

Comment: @teuneboon: Well, yes there is something else that needs to be fixed, but using `$('#id')` is not really slower and would be more consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to fix the problem:

1. You have to wrap the parameter passed to `getAndSaveValue` in quotation marks (otherwise you pass the variable `price_productID` (which is `undefined`) to the function and not the string):

   ```
   onclick="getAndSaveValue('price_productID')"
   //                    ---^            ---^
   ```
2. Pass the element directly:

   ```
   onclick="getAndSaveValue(this)"
   ```

   then you have to change the function to:

   ```
   function getAndSaveValue(element) {
       var thisValue = element.value;
   }
   ```

---

*Side note*: At least for element retrieval and traversing, I would use jQuery consistently. In solution #2 it is not necessary, but in #1, you could change your code to:

```
onclick="getAndSaveValue('#price_productID')"
//                     ---^
```

and

```
var thisValue = $(elementId).val();
```

Answer (score 1):

the price_productID is undefined...

instead of :

---

input type="button" value="save new price" onclick="getAndSaveValue(**price_productID**)"

### use:

input type="button" value="save new price" onclick="getAndSaveValue('#thisProductPrices')"

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for taking the time to answer. No this is not the problem, I have tested the values passed to the function and they are all corrent.

Comment: Inside `getAndSaveValue`, `document.getElementById(elementID)` is used. Prepending the ID with `#` is for jQuery. But you are right that it should be passed as a string.

Comment: Ok, seems I`ve misunderstood the context... what type of DOM elem is having the 'price_productID' id? is it an input?

Comment: See the second line in the OPs second code example. Yes, it is an `input` element.

Answer (score 1):

Load runs asynchronously(it kind of runs "in the background"). If you do something like this it should work:
//function to load data

```
function loadProductPrices(var1, callBack)
{
    //#thisProductPrices is the data container
    $('#thisProductPrices').load('filename.php', { 'var1': var1}, callBack);
}

//function to get element value after previous function has been called 
//(this one is called by a button that is part of the content that has 
//been generated by the previous call) 
function getAndSaveValue(elementID)
{
    var thisValue = document.getElementById(elementID).value; // this returns null (?)
    // after I have the new value I will post and save, using jquery again.
}

loadProductPrices('bla',function() {
    getAndSaveValue('elementId');
});
```

This will only call getAndSaveValue once you're sure filename.php is loaded.

Comment: `getAndSaveValue` should be called when a button is clicked, not automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to write the "getAndSaveValue" function end of jquery..

```
$(document).ready({

    function loadProductPrices(var1)
    {

        //#thisProductPrices is the data container

       $('#thisProductPrices').load('filename.php', { 'var1': var1});

    }

});

function getAndSaveValue(elementID){

    var thisValue=document.getElementById(elementID).value;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent example of how working while being in need for sleep is not recommended. I am sorry, there was nothing wrong with the code I have shown you, the mistake was completely mine and it took me 10 seconds to realize after I had a good nap...

The functions above are a bit more complex in reality, and at some point I did the fatal mistake to alter the contents of the container with a 'loading please wait' message and then check for values... for elements that would not exist in the DOM anymore of course... :)

Please excuse me for this. I will mark everyone's answer as useful (they all, after all, in a right direction).

What did we learn from this? Sleep over a problem and then ask :)